# unable to see any logs after updating cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

Suddenly I am not getting any logs except deployment logs for google cloud functions

Till now it worked fine but, after updating the function I haven't seen any logs. So I have done some research and deleted the cloud functions logs file and also the cloud function and again I have created a new function. Even then I am not able to see any logs related to the project excepted audit logs (i.e whenever the function gets updated)

Any clues what's wrong? I am not able to understand what exact problem.

any help is appreciated

Comment: What's your language? And how d you log? Have you code samples?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Language used is node.js, and logging with the statement console.log('hello')

Comment: An issue is in progress: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191 (scroll to the down). Python 3.8 is now OK, python 37 and node are still in error.

Comment: what was the issue and workaround for it? I am facing similar issue.. cloud function is running fine it just has topped logging of it..

Answer (score 1):

I have viewed the Issue Tracker  issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191 and have found that work is still being done to address the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see - and this is recent - is using View logs from the UI does not show any results:

[image]

Clicking View logs will create a query that looks something like this.  There are no results.

```
resource.type = "cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name = "projects/my-integrations/locations/us-central1/functions/my-integrations"
resource.labels.region = "us-central1"
```

You need to change the `resource.labels.function_name` part to just the function name to yield results.  Change the name and then click Run Query.

```
resource.type = "cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name = "my-integrations"
resource.labels.region = "us-central1"
```

This is for a Gen1 Cloud Function